# How can I prove that $y-x+x^{5}-\frac{xy^{4}}{2(1+x^{2})^{2}}-\frac{x^{3}}{1+y^{2}}>0$ when $x>0$ and $1<y<1.5$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I would like to prove that
$$y-x+x^{5}-\frac{xy^{4}}{2(1+x^{2})^{2}}-\frac{x^{3}}{1+y^{2}}>0$$
for all real numbers $x > 0$ and $1 < y < 1.5$. This seems true when plotted on WolframAlpha, but I don't know how to prove it. I tried replacing some of the terms using the given inequalities to obtain a simpler function, but any perturbation I make seems to render the inequality untrue. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: With such statements, I am ready to bet that the minimum of the lhs corresponds to $y=1$ or $y=1.5$.

Comment: The minimum for any fixed $x$? So I should try to prove that the expression is always positive for $y=1$ and $y=1.5$, that the derivative is positive at $y=1$, and that the derivative only vanishes once in the region... from which positivity across the region follows, I think?

Comment: The minimumof the lhs wrt $x$ and $y$ must correspond to one of the bounds of $y$ (otherwise the problem is a monster).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(y)=y-x+x^{5}-\frac{xy^{4}}{2(1+x^{2})^{2}}-\frac{x^{3}}{1+y^{2}}.$

Thus, $$f''(y)=-\frac{6xy^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+2x^3\left(\frac{y}{(1+y^2)^2}\right)'=$$
$$=-\frac{6xy^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+2x^3\left(\frac{1}{(1+y^2)^2}-\frac{4y^2}{(1+y^2)^3}\right)=$$
$$=-\frac{6xy^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\frac{2x^3(1-3y^2)}{(1+y^2)^3}<0,$$
which says that $f$ is a concave function.

But the concave function gets a minimal value for extreme value of $y$,

which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for $y\in\{1,1.5\}.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you.

Comment: @chaos  You are welcome!

Comment: don't catch the idea, is it mean the 2nd derivative always have a negative value in the range of $1<y<1.5$?

Comment: @chuackl Yes, exactly.

Comment: I see so we need to find the min value of y in between 1 and 1.5, show with this y,$f(y)$ is bigger than 0 for this number?

Comment: @chuackl  It's enough to prove that $f(1)>0$ and $f(1.5)>0.$ Draw a graph of some concave on $[1,1.5]$ function.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$g(y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(y-x+x^{5}-\frac{xy^{4}}{2(1+x^{2})^{2}}-\frac{x^{3}}{1+y^{2}}\right) =1-\frac{2xy^3}{(1+x^2)^2}+\frac{2x^3y}{(1+y^2)^2}$$

with

$$g'(y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(y-x+x^{5}-\frac{xy^{4}}{2(1+x^{2})^{2}}-\frac{x^{3}}{1+y^{2}}\right) =-\frac{6xy^2}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{2x^3(-1+3y^2)}{(1+y^2)^3}<0$$

therefore the minimum is reached either for $y=1$ or $y=\frac32$, therefore we reduce to check and

$$x^5-\frac1{2}x^3-\frac{x}{2(x^2+1)^2}-x+1>0 \tag 1$$

$$x^5-\frac4{13}x^3-\frac{81}{32}\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}-x+\frac32>0 \tag 2$$

Comment: I think the minimum can also occur at $y = 1$ following this argument, so we would need to check the initial equation for both $y=1$ and $y=3/2$.

Comment: @chaos Since $g(1)>0$ and $g'(y)<0$ we have that the minimum occurs for $y=\frac32$.

Comment: The minimum of $g$, yes, but not necessarily the minimum of the initial function $f$.

Comment: @chaos Yes of course! I've mixed up thinge here. I try to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, this works :)

Comment: Is there any trick to directly spot why g(1)>0 for x>0? I can only see x>1,g(1)>0. How about 0<x<1? Do you ppl plot graph?

Comment: @chuackl The comment is referring to my first answer which contained some erroneous evaluation.  We can reduce the expression to to $x^7 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^4 + x^3 + 2 x^2+2(x-1)^2$.